# PHP - Select Array from List of Arrays in Foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array of arrays. Each array contains a user's information (name, email, username, etc). When a user is logged in, the page needs to display the arrays in a table. (This is working fine)

```
<table>

    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user'])) {
            echo '<tr>';
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($item_names); $i++) {
                if ($i == 8) continue;
                echo "<th scope=\"col\">$item_names[$i]</th>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';
            $altrow = false;
            foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
                echo ($altrow) ? '<tr class="alt">' : '<tr>';
                $altrow = !$altrow;
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($contact); $i++) {
                    if ($i == 8) continue;
                    echo "<td>$contact[$i]</td>";
                }
                echo '</tr>'; 
            }
        }
    ?> 
</table>
```

But I would also like the table to highlight the array(row) of the specific logged in user.

I have tried (and failed):

```
<table>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user'])) {
            echo '<tr>';
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($item_names); $i++) {
                if ($i == 8) continue;
                echo "<th scope=\"col\">$item_names[$i]</th>";
            }
            echo '</tr>'
            $altrow = false;
            foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
                if ($contact[1] == $_SESSION['logged_in_user']) {
                    echo '<tr class="highlight">' : '<tr>'; 
                } else {
                    echo ($altrow) ? '<tr class="alt">' : '<tr>';
                    $altrow = !$altrow;
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($contact); $i++) {
                        if ($i == 8) continue;
                            echo "<td>$contact[$i]</td>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</tr>'; 
                }
            }
    ?> 
</table>
```

Am I not even close? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your indenting is confusing.  The ending bracket should at least be at the same indentation as the beginning block.  Not before it.

Comment: I'm going to attempt to indent your code properly.  Note that proper indentation allows errors to be more easily spotted.

Comment: I also recommend replacing tabs with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

hi yaar simply check tour loop
foreach ($contacts as $contact=>$value) {
//manipulate $value here and or you can check by printing $value here

}

Comment: This does not help the question.

Comment: Hi  can u post bit peace of array then i can explain u how to display
if your array is like array([0]=>array('name'=>'john')) and 
if you apply  foreach ($contacts as $contact=>$value) {
$value['name'] give u value john.......
}

Comment: The array goes like:

`$contacts = array (
    array(1000, "Garrett", "Salinas", ... 
    array(1001, "Xander", "Ryan", ...

Comment: well as i get your array is like array ( array(1000, "Garrett", "Ryan"), array(1001, "Xander", "Ryan")....)
You write foreach ($contacts as $_contact){ echo $_contact[0]; //this give u id}
Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try code given below

```
<table>
   <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user'])) {
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($item_names); $i++) {
            if ($i == 8) continue;
                echo "<th scope=\"col\">$item_names[$i]</th>";
         }
        echo '</tr>';

      $altrow = false;

      foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
        if ($contact[1] == $_SESSION['logged_in_user']) {
            echo '<tr class="highlight">'; 
        } else {
            echo ($altrow) ? '<tr class="alt">' : '<tr>';
         }   
           $altrow = !$altrow;
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($contact); $i++) {
                if ($i == 8) continue;
                     echo "<td>$contact[$i]</td>";
             }

            echo '</tr>'; 
         }
      }
   ?> 
</table>
```

There was some bracket mistake in your code like `} else {}`.

I hope it will be working for you.

thanks